# Mongoose: deep search

Tags: node.js, mongoose, find, mongoose-schema

I have a schema whose returns is below:

```
"_id": "61d4791786dbde4bb0ecd622",
"members": [
    {
        "score": 75,
        "_id": "61d4791886dbde4bb0ece492",
        "userId": "60df085d4729322a7464babc",
        "penalties": [
            {
                "_id": "61d4791886dbde4bb0ece493",
                "penaltyScore": -10
            },
            {
                "_id": "61d4791886dbde4bb0ece494",
                "penaltyScore": -15
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I want to find the register by `userId`. I tried to use:

```
ManeuverStatistics.find(userId && { members: { $in: userId } }).exec(
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: "failed!" });
        return;
      }
      res.status(200).send(data);
    }
  );
```

But it did not work... How can I make a deep search to find content that matches with the `userId`  inside the `members` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some hours trying to solve it, but I found a possible solution. To help any other programmer, here it's my approach:

```
ManeuverStatistics.find(userId && { "members.userId": userId }).exec(
  (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: "failed!" });
      return;
    }
    res.status(200).send(data);
  }
);
```

Basically, I could access the key `userId` inside the object using `members.userId`.